# How can I output a category title followed by indented text from a checkbox in Dash-Plotly?

Tags: html, python-3.x, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am trying to create the following output (assuming all checkboxes are clicked) with the help of dash:

```
US:      MTL
         NYC 
         SF

Europe:  BER 
         AMS 
         PAR
```

If none of the checkboxes are selected, then neither "US:" nor "Europe" should be displayed.
If let's say only AMS is selected, then I would only display "Europe" and "AMS", but nothing else. In my actual code, I have many more categories and options but please find below the basic version for illustration, of what I currently have.

Thanks guys!

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import time

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    #Output
    html.Div(id='my-div-checklist1'),

    #Clickboxes
    dcc.Checklist(id='my-checklist1',
    options=[
        {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
        {'label': 'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
        {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
    ],
    value=[]
    ),

    html.Hr(),



    dcc.Checklist(id='my-checklist2',
    options=[
        {'label': 'Berlin', 'value': 'BER'},
        {'label': 'Amsterdam', 'value': 'AMS'},
        {'label': 'Paris', 'value': 'PAR'}
    ],
    value=[],
    labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
    ),
    html.Div(id='my-div-checklist2'),
    html.Hr(),


])




@app.callback(Output('my-div-checklist1', 'children'),
              [Input('my-checklist1', 'value'),
              Input('my-checklist2', 'value')
              ])

def prepare_data(categ1, categ2):
        return html.Div([dcc.Markdown(
        str(" ".join(categ1 )) + " " + '\n' + '\n' +
        str(" ".join(categ2)))])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: You want the output to be text? Or are you asking about HTML/dcc components' layout and their CSS?

Comment: Hi. Yes the output should be text. From what I can tell, it will be only dcc.

Currently, its all in one row, has no intention and the category is either displayed all the times or never. It should be dependent on whether the box is checked or not. thx

Comment: I am aware of:
'''
html.H3("Your favorite city within:"), html.Div(id='my-div-checklist1', style={'padding-left': '115px'}),
'''
but that will create padding for all of it. I just want the text from the checkboxes with padding. The category titles should be without padding. Thx

Comment: How about `html.Pre`? It preserves the indentation of your Python string.